# How can ViewModel tell my custom control change in my property?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a Custom Control call "MyControl".  And it has a property 'ControlLists' which is a IList.  And I bind a viewModel 'MyViewModel' to that my custom control. And 'MyViewModel' has a ViewModelLists which bind to the ControlLists.

Like this:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
        <myapp:MyControl
         ControlLists="{Binding ViewModelLists}"
        />
  </DataTemplate>
```

My question is if My ViewModel makes changes (add/remove) to its ViewModelLists, how can it tell 'MyControl' that to refresh its 'ControlList'?

In MyViewModel, I have

```
 public override IList<Items> ViewModelLists {
      return myList;// myList is ObserverableCollection<Items>
 }
```

In MyControl, I have

```
 public IList<Items> ControlLists
        {
            get
            {
             ...
             }
             set
             {
              ...
              }
           }
```

My question is when I setup breakpoint in the setting of MyControl, why the value is always null? I expect it to be the ObserverableCollection in my ViewModel that I bind to in.

Does setter of the properties of my control being called when I bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the property bound to ControlLists is an ObservableCollection, it will auto notify the bound control as items are added and removed or cleared. There is also a "CollectionChanged" event you can subscribe to if you need to react to items as they are added and removed from the list...

However, I believe this is ignored if you are setting the bound collection property directly, that is, you initializing the collection by setting its value directly to a collection of items, like:

```
public ObservableCollection<Things> TheThings {get;set;}
```

and

```
TheThings = new ObservableCollection<Things>(listOfthings);
```

In that case, you want to change the collection property from an autoproperty to a full property with backing value so you can raise notifypropertychanged when the value changes, like this

```
        private ObservableCollection<Things> theThings= new ObservableCollection<Things>();
    public ObservableCollection<Things> TheThings
    {
        get { return this.theThings; }
        set
        {
            this.theThings= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(); // <-- something like this
        }
    }
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you expose your ViewModelLists as an ObservableCollection then the control will automatically know when the list changes.

Comment: More precisely, the ObservableCollection will raise a `CollectionChanged` event. It is up to your control to either handle it or use the collection in a control that can handle it (usually something that inherits from ItemsControl).